# Test coverage for Autowired class inside mock class

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have the below structure and I have an issue that my test that I'm not able to reach the Autowired class `DataLoader.getListForName` from my `MyHelperTest.testGetDataAsList`. Meaning when I run my test the flow doesn't even go to the `getListForName` method. What is that Im missing

```
@Component
public class MyHelper{
@Autowired
private DataLoader dataLoader;

public List<String> getDataAsList(String name, boolean flag)
{
    List<String> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
    dataList.addAll(dataLoader.getListForName(name,flag));
    return dataList;
}
}
```

=====

```
@Component
public class DataLoader{
    Map<String,List<String>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
    public List<String> getListForName(String name, boolean flag){
        if(flag) return myMap.get(name); 
    }
}
```

=====

```
public class MyHelperTest{
    @InjectMocks
    private MyHelper myHelper;

    @Mock
    private DataLoader dataLoader;

    @Test
    public void testGetDataAsList(){
        List<String> myList = myHelper.getDataAsList("test1",true);
        assertTrue(myList.contains("Age"));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

since you have mocked out `dataLoader`, it has no valuable action before you define it.
For example:
if you want to call `.getDataAsList("test1", true)`
you need to set

```
Mockito.when(myHelper.getDataAsList("test1", true).thenReturn(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Age")));
```

before you call it.

remember that mock always generate a mock object without any real properties or methods, not a real object that has all its properties or methods defined